Does Gravity Well work with Blade Ward?
Gravity well says:

whenever you cast a spell on a creature, you can move the target 5 feet to an unoccupied space of your choice if the target is willing to move, the spell hits it with an attack, or it fails a saving throw against the spell.

Blade Ward has a range of self and has some effect on "you", however does not specifically target.
The question is whether I get to move myself using Blade Ward as a lvl 6 Graviturgy Wizard.
Considering that I'm definitely willing to move, the only doubt is in whether Blade Ward is a spell cast on myself. It definitely has some effect on me, but I can't find a clear definition of what casting a spell on someone means or what can be considered a target.

Hi Hessian and welcome to the site!  This is a great first question; you have a clearly defined problem, show what research you have already done by including the text of gravity well, and have properly tagged the question itself.  Well done!  If you have any questions about the site itself, please take a look at the help center and take the tour when you have a chance.  Happy stacking!

Thanks for the green check!  Please be aware that we generally leave answers up for some time, at least a day, to see what else comes in - another answerer might have been about to respond with something you like better (perhaps Eddymage or DaleM would write something more direct and to the point even if it agreed with my answer), and accepting the answer early might discourage that.  But regardless, I'm glad you found the answer helpful!

I see, I'll leave it up a bit longer and accept it again later if nothing better comes up, but thanks for the detailed answer already!

Why would it not?
As you state, this works if the blade ward targets yourself.  Gravity well, like many spells, triggers on a specific targeting.  Despite this, and perhaps by design1, many (if not most) spells in 5e-2014 do not explicitly state their targets.
Thus, we are expected to determine in each case what the 'target' (in the natural English sense) of a spell would be.  And in the case of blade ward, which says (emphasis mine):

Until the end of your next turn, you have resistance against bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing damage dealt by weapon attacks.

what else could the target be?  By a common sense reading, and assuming that the target is 'a creature, object, or point of origin', the target of the spell being you is the only possibility that makes sense.
If you would like some more support for this reading, that the spell actually targets you, we note that the spell has a Range of Self.  As the PHB says:

Other spells, such as the shield spell, affect only you2. These spells have a range of self.

The PHB says that all spells that affect only you have a range of self - but do all spells that have a range of self target only you?
There is not an official answer to that, but we can use a JC tweet for the unofficial RAI:

A range of self means the caster is the target, as in shield, or the point of origin, as in thunderwave (PH, 202).

Since blade ward is not an AoE spell, it follows that the range of self must mean that you are the target of the spell.

1 As SevenSidedDie says, "D&D 5th edition is not a keyword-driven game; quite the opposite: the designers deliberately avoided writing using keywords where possible in favour of describing the rules in what they dubbed “natural language.”* Lacking the word target is therefore not significant."
2 Clearly these spells don't actually affect only you - both shield and blade ward also affect attacks made against you - but there is likely an implicit 'at the time of casting' in there, as there is in other spells.
